# Avg memory access time

Tags: architecture, system

With swapping, memory can be viewed as a cache for pages stored on disk.  If it takes 100 ns to access memory, 10 ms to access disk, and our cache hit rate is 0.95, then what is the average memory access time, in ms? (provide only two significant digits in your answer)

I've looked around and can't figure it out. My friend is also having the same issue and this is what we got so far: 
0.95 * 100ns + 0.05 * 10ms. He says that 0.05 comes from 1 - 0.95. I just want to know if this is the right setup and if the 0.5 is correct.

Thanks.

Comment: This edit is what I've in my answer, except that I converted ns to ms already.

Answer (score 0):

`0.05*10 + 0.95*0.0001 = 0.5001 ms`.

Note: StackOverflow is not for maths or exam questions.

Edit: think that 95% of the times you don't need to access disk, so these take `100ns = 0.0001ms`. And 5% you need, which take `10ms`. You need to sum these to get 100% of the times, which is an average already.